# The set of positive intersection measure

Tags: measure-theory

Let $(X,S,\mu)$ a $\sigma$-finite mesure space. Let $ B \subset S$ a consistent family of disjoint sets. Let $ E \in S$ with $ \mu(E)>0$. Prove that the family $ D_E = $ {$ D \in B : \mu(E\cap B)>0$} is countable.

When $ \mu(E)=\infty$, I don't know how to procede. The case $ \mu(E)<\infty$ I have done it.

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE.  You might want to try applying your argument for the case $\mu(E) \lt \infty$ to the countable sequence of subsets given by the definition of $\sigma$-finite (for which [see here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%CE%A3-finite_measure)).  You might add some details of your work and fix (edit) some spelling problems in your post at the same time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write $X=\bigcup_n F_n$ where $\mu(F_n) < +\infty$, by definition of being $\sigma$-finite.

Now $E = \bigcup_n (E \cap F_n)$ is a decomposition of $E$ into finite-measure parts. Now if $D_E$ is uncountable, this means that some $D_{E \cap F_n}$ is uncountable by the pigeon hole principle. Note that

$$D_E = \bigcup_n D_{E\cap F_n}$$

(if $\mu(D \cap E)>0$ there must be some $F_n$ such that $\mu(D \cap (E \cap F_n))>0$...)

Now you can apply the finite case to $E \cap F_n$ and have a contradiction.

Comment: Thank you, your answer help me very much.